# “He’s made new friends when he changed roles”

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, simple-past

Present perfect and past simple in the same sentence?

> He’s made new friends when he changed roles.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Doesn't sound quite right. '_Since_ he changed roles' would be better - he presumably didn't make all the friends at the exact time that he changed.

Comment: Thank you
so it's wrong to say; He’s made new friends when he changed roles.
I need a grammar analyses if you have any source, please?

Comment: I deliberately avoided saying that it was grammatically wrong - I just told you that I found it awkward. However [this](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/present-perfect-tense/) article on the present perfect tense says that it isn't used when the action took place at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the right way to say it, whatever "it" may be. Time, since we don't understand it, is always referred to in metaphors, and the most common way is as a time line with points and segments on it, like geometry. English distinguishes **points** of time, like *at 3 pm*, with **lengths** of time, like *until 3 pm*. They tend to take different prepositions, and appear in different constructions.

*He's made new friends*, like all present perfect clauses, refers to a length of past time starting at an unknown point in the past and leading up to the present.

*When he changed roles*, on the other hand, refers to a point in past time, not a length. You can use that point as the beginning of the length referred to in the first clause with *since*, as @Kate suggested; but *when* normally doesn't refer to a stretch of time delimited by the present perfect.